# Applying a function to an entire DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Probably a trivial question, but how does one apply a function to an entire "matrix" with Pandas? It seems to me that apply either works row-wise or column-wise, but what if I want to do both? E.g.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10,20,30], "B": [20, 30, 10]})
>>> df
    A   B  
0  10  20         
1  20  40         
2  30  10  
>>> df.apply(max)
40
```

With some pre-defined max function. Many thanks in advance

Edit:
Apologies, I should have been more clear in my original question. I am not actually interested in calculating a DataFrame max, rather it was just meant as an example. Perhaps a better example, would be a function that takes the max of the last two rows over both columns, ie.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10,20,30], "B": [20, 30, 10]})
>>> df
    A   B  
0  10  20         
1  20  40         
2  30  10 
3  50  20 
>>> df.apply(max)
0  n/a
1  40
2  40
3  50
```

Comment: `df.max().max()` for this case.

Comment: you can use NumPy: `np.amax(df.values)`

Comment: well actually first you can write `df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10,20,30], "B": [20, 30, 10]}, dtype=np.float)` and then apply some function (e.g. exp) as follows: `exp_df = np.exp(df)`
if you want to find the max values in the rows and columns you can do: `df.max()`

Comment: if you want to find the max value in the table, the best way to do it is this:
`df.values.max()`

Comment: `.applymap` works on every element, but you should just use the max method built-in to dataframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually not the way a DataFrame is used, since the columns may have different types.

If, however, all columns have the same type, it may be sensible to cast the DataFrame to a matrix, like

```
m = df.as_matrix()
```

and then work with `m`, e.g.

```
m.max()
```

Comment: That does not look like python.

Comment: Oh sorry, it was R... I changed it in python

Comment: dataframes have `.max` methods. just use that.